# Jquery Input Mask (Redefine numeric "9")

Tags: javascript, jquery, input-mask

I'm using RobinHerbots jquery input mask.
How to redefine the "9", so the mask will show XXXX91 instead of XXXXX1?

EDIT: if possible I would like to make last two digits uneditable

```js
var autoPopulateNo = 91  //how to show the mask like this XXXX91

$("#number").inputmask({
"mask": "9999" + autoPopulateNo,
clearMaskOnLostFocus: false,
placeholder:"X",

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>
<form action="">  
  <div>
    <label for="number">Mask</label>
    <input id="number" type="text"/>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use **["escapeChar"](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask#escapechar)**

Definition of the symbols used to escape a part in the mask.

> escapeChar: "\\"

```js
var autoPopulateNo = "\\91"  //how to show the mask like this XXXX91

$("#number").inputmask({
"mask": "9999" + autoPopulateNo,
clearMaskOnLostFocus: false,
placeholder:"X",

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>
<form action="">  
  <div>
    <label for="number">Mask</label>
    <input id="number" type="text"/>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: this one works, very helpful...Thanks sooo much, +1 :)

Comment: no problem. thanks for the feedback. good luck in your project.

Answer (score 4):

Use `placeholder: "XXXX91"` instead of `placeholder:"X"`. 
If you need to escape the `9` in your mask,  use `\\` symbol:

```
$("#number").inputmask({ 
  "mask": "9999\\91",
  clearMaskOnLostFocus: false,
  placeholder:"XXXX91"
});
```

Comment: `<input id="number" type="text"/>91`

Comment: @JaromandaX it is possible to put it inside the input instead of outside?

Comment: possibly, I just offered that as a "solution" :p

Comment: @Rick, I have updated my answer. Try to escape `9` symbol.

Comment: Thanks for the everyone help, u guys are amazing

Answer (score 0):

In `masked.input.min.js` file find:

```
translation:{
    0: {
        pattern: /\d/
    },
    "#": {
        pattern: /\d/,
        recursive: !0
    },
    A: {
        pattern: /[a-zA-Z0-9]/
    }
}
```

this part and delete:

```
9: {
    ...
}
```